# Unable to scroll when there are multiple vertical scrolls available in app

Tags: android, automation, appium

Th screen of my app contains two scrollable elements. I am not able to select which particular page to scroll to.

I have tried this:

Logic 1:

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(“new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(“com.marrow:id/tvIndexTitle”)).getChildByText(”+ “new UiSelector().className(“android.widget.TextView”), “ADVANCED ORTHOPAEDICS & MANAGEMENT”)”));
```

Logic 2:

```
MobileElement element = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(“new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(“com.marrow:id/tvIndexTitle”)).scrollIntoView(” + “new UiSelector().text(“ADVANCED ORTHOPAEDICS & MANAGEMENT”))”));
```

I am not able to perform any scroll operation.
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases you specified the **same id** of scrollable view:

```
new UiSelector().resourceId(“com.marrow:id/tvIndexTitle”)
```

It explains why you are scrolling within **the same boundaries**

Suggestions:

- Find the id of your 2nd scrollable view and replace `tvIndexTitle` or try with index: `new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(1)`
- Don't search for exact text: `new UiSelector().text(...)`, use `textContains` or `textStartsWith`

Example:

```
        MobileElement element = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(1)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"ADVANCED ORTHOPAEDICS\"))";
```

Comment: It started working when I changed "instance(1)" to "instance(2)". Thanks a lot sit